# gzip not compressing text - Angular

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, gzip

I'm unable to get my gzip to work when deploying app to azure blob storage.
I tried installing `gzipper` and per the docs:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build && gzipper compress ./dist"
}
```

set this. Afterwards I pushed my code to GitHub which kicked off my CI/CD pipeline.
Also my build cmd in the pipeline is as follows (not sure if this is relevant):

```
run build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --build-optimizer
```

I also tried `gzip-all` and got a better result with Google Lighthouse. It brought my score from 23 to 66 and my site does appear to be a little faster on load time, but gzip isn't working fully apparently. This is the cmd I used in package.json with `gzip-all` to `ng build --prod && gzip-all dist/*` that increased my score. Am I missing a step?

[image]

from gzip check site:

[image]

Comment: You need to enable gzip in your server, apache, nginx or whatever else you are serving it with. Do you know what kind of server you are running?

Comment: It's running on Azure storage blob

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Azure Storage Blobs but it seems that on top of the compression which you have already done, you need to set a header:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance